# taking fringe ideas mainstream

Tags: phrase-usage

Does "taking fringe ideas mainstream" mean "making fringe ideas mainstream" - that is, the ideas that were less important, or the fringe ideas, were made very important, equal to mainstream in the Trump era?

After consulting some dictionaries, I discovered that it possibly means "receiving fringe ideas as mainstream". I am not sure.

> Tracking QAnon: how Trump turned conspiracy-theory research upside down
> By **taking fringe ideas mainstream**, the former US president taught new and dangerous lessons about manipulating social and mass media.

> Source:  [Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-00257-y)

Comment: Not made "very important" but made "not weird" basically. Things that before may have been unthinkable are now ideas that everyone has been exposed to - it doesn't necessarily mean that everyone now agrees with them, just that they're now part of the mainstream conversation.

Comment: Thank you.  Are "taking fringe ideas mainstream" and "making fringe ideas mainstream" interchangeable there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does "taking fringe ideas mainstream" mean "making fringe ideas
> mainstream" - that is, the ideas that were less important, or the
> fringe ideas, were made very important, equal to mainstream in the
> Trump era?

*Taking an idea mainstream* and *making an idea mainstream* could mean the same thing, but they could also mean something different, depending on context.

Consider:

```
I want to help take this idea mainstream by putting it on Twitter.    < OK

I want to help make this idea mainstream by Tweeting it every day.    < OK
```

"Taking fringe ideas mainstream" could refer to the initial method used but not the effective process.  It could also emphasize the transposition of ideas. "Making fringe ideas mainstream" refers to the effort, the process.

For example:

```
Facebook takes fringe ideas mainstream by giving an audience to lunatics who then make those ideas normal.

Does Facebook make fringe ideas mainstream?  No, they do not do it, but they certainly enable it to happen.
```